# Ставится ли двоеточие (тире) в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие, бсп

Жизнь на базе, используемой исключительно для опытов, чрезвычайно скучна (: —) кроме исследовательского центра и армии, которая занимает гарнизон, тут больше ничего нет.

Comment: Максим, а вы не могли бы добавить еще одно предложение., следующее за этим. Дело в то, что, как мне кажется, выбор знака может зависеть от контекста.

Answer (score 2):

*Жизнь на базе, используемой исключительно для опытов, чрезвычайно скучна: кроме исследовательского центра и армии, которая занимает гарнизон, тут больше ничего нет.*

Это «классический» случай использования [**двоеточия в бессоюзном сложном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_44.htm).

> 6. Если вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения указывает основание или причину того, о чем говорится в первой части, то между частями ставится двоеточие (между частями можно вставить причинные союзы *потому что, так как, поскольку* и т. п.): <...> *Напрасно вы смотрите кругом во все стороны: нет выхода из бесконечных тундр* (Гонч.) <...> *Птиц не было слышно: они не поют в часы зноя* (Т.)...

[**Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#) обычно ставится, когда причина указывается в первой части.

> Ср.: *Выйти невозможно: на улице проливной дождь* — основное содержание заключено в первой части, во второй указывается причина; *На улице проливной дождь — выйти невозможно* — причина указывается в первой части, во второй приводится следствие, вывод, что составляет основу высказывания...

P. S. Постановка тире ошибкой не будет, а часто выглядит даже предпочтительней, особенно когда вторая часть бессоюзного предложения имеет пояснительно-присоединительный характер. Выбор делается и в зависимости от интонации. В случае двоеточия мы практически «ставим точку», то есть понижаем тон голоса. Если же в конце первой части голос повышается и делается тоническое ударение (в нашем примере на слове «скучна»), имеет смысл использовать тире.
«Самые многочисленные случаи вариативности знаков препинания — параллельное употребление двоеточия и тире» (Справочник Розенталя, [***ДВОЕТОЧИЕ — ТИРЕ***](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189)).

Answer (score 0):

***Жизнь на базе, используемой исключительно для опытов, чрезвычайно скучна (: —) кроме исследовательского центра и армии, которая занимает гарнизон, тут больше ничего нет.***

1. К  выбору тире или  двоеточия в подобных предложениях **не стоит подходить формально:**  действительно, причина указана во втором предложении, и по правилам в этом случае ставится двоеточие.
2. Но  давайте вспомним еще и о том, что обобщенным значение двоеточия является **общее пояснительное значение**: ведь и сама причина – это своего рода пояснение предыдущего содержания. Также у двоеточия **ярко выраженная интонация**  (это так называемое интонационное предупреждение): понижение тона и значительно увеличенная пауза.
3. **Вот поэтому так важен контекст**, и задачи не всегда решаются на уровне одного предложения. Если и дальше будет раскрываться именно причина скуки, то двоеточие будет на месте, но, возможно, автор **перейдет** к другой теме.

А вот тире здесь **присоединительное**, пауза только обозначена, но не подчеркнута. Возможно,  дальше автор эту тему не будет продолжать. Тогда описание структуры гарнизона будет закрыто, то есть это будет только краткое информационное сообщение о положении вещей.

4. **Примеры**

(1) Жизнь на базе, используемой исключительно для опытов, чрезвычайно скучна:  кроме исследовательского центра и армии, которая занимает гарнизон, тут больше ничего нет.  *И природа здесь довольно скудная – ни леса, ни парка, ни какой-либо речушки…*

(2) Жизнь на базе, используемой исключительно для опытов, чрезвычайно скучна –  кроме исследовательского центра и армии, которая занимает гарнизон, тут больше ничего нет.  *Но люди везде пытаются как-то украсить свою жизнь,  найти хотя бы какие-то радости в своем существовании. И всегда находятся такие неугомонные «организаторы», притягивающие к себе внимание остальных…*